# Please tell me the bug in this code of 2D dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have used [this web link as reference](http://www.eumus.edu.uy/eme/c/c-notes_summit/intermediate/sx9.html).

The following code is generating this debug error:
[image]

I am unable to find the bug. Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 5

main()
{
    char ** my2dArray = NULL;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * ROWS);

    for(i=0 ; i<ROWS ; i++)
    {
        my2dArray[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * COLS);
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<ROWS ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<COLS ; j++)
        {
            my2dArray[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
        }
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<ROWS ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<COLS ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d, ", my2dArray[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<ROWS ; i++)
    {
        free(my2dArray[i]);
    }

    free(my2dArray);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Code Review is strictly for working code. I've migrated your question to a more appropriate venue.

Comment: Never typecast the result of malloc in C. It hides away bugs and compiler warnings. Multiple posts about that topic can be found on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing items of type `char*` in `my2dArray[i]`:

```
my2dArray[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * COLS);
```

`char` is 1 byte, `char*` is 4 or 8 byte, so you're not allocating enough memory for `my2dArray` at the moment, change it to this:

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ROWS);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * ROWS);
```

should be

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ROWS);
```

You are allocate enough space for an array of char, but you need enough space for an array of char pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate space for the pointers (note the extra `*`):

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ROWS);
```

Note: have you thought about using a one dimension array? eg: `[i * COLS + j]`

Answer (score 0):

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * ROWS);
```

You want that to be

```
my2dArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ROWS);
```

since you are storing arrays there.